# Android referral tracking

Tags: android, referrals

Please advice a plan/technology/tutorials to implement this on android.

I have premium users and ordinary users. The premium users are a group of five levels, where level 1 are direct users, level 2 are referred by level 1 and level 3 are referred by level 2 and so on.

1) I need to give special link to level 1 premium users to download the app so as to identify them during install. Advice on this.

2) Premium users give link (to refer) to next level users for downloading the app. So how to know the referrer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v1/devguide#campaigns ?

You can also use a service like www.mobileapptracking.com